# LinQ to objects GroupBy() by object and Sum() by amount

Tags: .net, linq, grouping, linq-to-objects

I have a pretty simple case which I started solving using foreach(), but then I thought I could do it using Linq.

Basically I have `IList` that contains `PaymentTransaction` objects and there are 2 properties `Dealer` and `Amount`.

I want to `GroupBy()` by `Dealer` and `Sum()` by `Amount`.

I tried to accomplish this using following code, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
var test = paymentTransactionDao.GetAll().GroupBy(x => x.Dealer).Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear on what you really want the result to be, so I assume that you want to sum up the amounts in each group:

```
var test =
  paymentTransactionDao.GetAll()
  .GroupBy(x => x.Dealer)
  .Select(g => new { Dealer = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Amount) });
```

Comment: @gabe: I don't know, I don't assume anything about what kind of object that is or what the method does other than that is returns a collection.

Answer (score 2):

GroupBy will return a bunch of `IGrouping<string, PaymentTransaction>` (assuming Dealer is a string). Try this:

```
...GroupBy(...).Select(x => new {Dealer=x.Key, Amount=x.Sum(xx => xx.Amount)});
```

(Just guessing, as I'm not in front of VS.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [groupby overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493.aspx) which removes the need for the select by taking a sequence according to its key thus creating a result value from each group and key. Each of the elements is then projected:

```
GroupBy(pt => pt.Dealer,
        pt => pt.Amount,
        (dealer, amount) => new {
                                  Dealer = dealer,
                                  TotalAmount = amount.Sum()
                                }
        )
```